# Creating a modular document

Tags: fontsize, document-configuration

I have already created 25 different files that I whish to include in a long document. My first attempt is as shown below:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} % Typical maths resource packages
\usepackage{graphics}                 % Packages to allow inclusion of graphics
\usepackage{color}                    % For creating coloured text and background
\usepackage{hyperref}               % For creating hyperlinks in cross references
\usepackage{xfrac}                     % For creating inline fractions        
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\graphicspath{my_images}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}

\input{Chapter1.2}

\end{document}
```

File Chapter1.2 is:

```
\chapter{Contravariant and Covariant Tensors - Part 1}
Let's begin with two curvilinear coordinates systems as shown in Figure 1.1 
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{Curv_Coord}
\caption{Curvilinear Coordinate systems}
\end{center}
\label{myfig1.1}
\end{figure}
and assume that we know how to transform from one system to the other so that if we know the components of a contravariant tensor in the x-coordinate system, we know its components in the y-coordiante system by an equation such as:
```

The difficulty I have is that I want to have a smaller font size for the Chapter title - Contravariant and Covariant Tensors - Part 1 - Furthermore, where should I write the command that would allow such font change, in main.tex or in Chapter 1.2.tx

Unfortunately, after many hours of trial and error, I have to admit defeat.

Can someone help with this problem? Thank you kindkly

Comment: the fonts used in chapters (you may as well use the facilities of `titlesec` since you are loading it anyway) seem to be unrelated to issues about modularity and file inclusion. If your question is about chapter fonts you could change the question title and make the example a single file example that people could run.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to do the font change in the main file:

```
\commandtochangechapterfont %for example from `titlesec`
\input{Chapter1.2}
\commandtochangechapterfontback %depends on the first command
```

If you change the way you handle the typesetting of chapters, you'll probably do this in main file. If that happens, it's easier to find this code in the main file, than in the chapter file.

> "Which chapter did I change the font size in last week?"

Comment: Ah, I had the grouping when I thought, that the code would only font changing commands. I forgot to delete them after I changed that.